# Should we have a tag for "Carleman matrix"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[Carleman matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix) are a special case of infinite matrices designed for function-composition. They involve implicitly the concept of generating-functions. They have certain specific properties which made me asking sometimes questions about this.
Searching for the term "[Carleman](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=carleman)" I get 53 results (not only my own questions).

For me they represent a specific class of problems, enough to have a tag for it. But that's my preference only. The tags [infinite-matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-matrices) and [matrix-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) exist and are two tags which might (or not) be sufficient...
What does the community suggest?

Comment: Searching only for [questions containing the words Carleman and matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=carleman+matrix+is:q) reduces this to 4 results. (But I don't think that the number of questions should be the only criterion when deciding when the tag is suitable.)

Comment: Ah, I see. I've also looked more precisely at the results and found also much about "Carleman theorem" and others. So the number of tags should likely not be increased by *such* a specific item...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I closed the case accepting Martin Sleziak's comment as relevant hint